# Generating pdf from XML response taking so much time

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I have xml in my database and wanted to generate pdf from xml, but if xml is too big then it through timeout error. I don't want to change my server timeout instead of how to improve the timing of pdf generate.
I am using `<pre>` tag for good formatting.

Below code for pdf generate

```
public function generateCreditReport($form, $path=false, $htmlPath=false){       
    $this->load->library('fpdf/fpdf');
    $this->load->library('fpdi/fpdi');
    if(!empty($path) && !file_exists($path)){
        $data['form'] =  $form;       
        $data['date'] = $data['xml'] = null;
        if($data['form']->credit_report != ''){ 
            try{
                $data['xml'] = new SimpleXMLElement($data['form']->credit_report);   
            }catch(Exception $e){

            }
            $timeStatus = $this->admin->get_timestamp($data['form']->id, 'credit_pulled');
            if(!empty($timeStatus)) {
                $data['date'] = $timeStatus->date;
            }
        }
        $pdf = new TCPDF();     
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
        $pdf->SetFontSize(10);
        $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
        $pdf->SetProtection(array('print','modify'),"$form->loan_id","sefinance",0);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $html = $this->load->view('admin/credit_report_pdf', $data,true);
        $generatedReport = file_put_contents($htmlPath, $html , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        $pdf->WriteHTML($html);

        if($path){
            $pdf->Output($path, "F");             
        }else{
            $pdf->Output(); 
        }
    }
}
```

View file `credit_report_pdf` is as below

```
<h4>Report Results</h4>
<br>
<?php if(!empty($xml)){ ?>
<?php echo print_credit($xml->EfxReport->USPrintImage); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I am formatting using `<pre>` to look good.

```
function print_credit($report) {
    $split = " <div style='page-break-before: always;'></div>" . repeater(' ', 43);
    $report = preg_replace('/\* \* \*[\s\S]+?USER REF./', $split, $report);
    $output = "";
    $output = '<pre>';
    $length = strlen($report);
    $count = $length / 81;
    $position = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if (strpos(substr($report, $position, 80), 'THIS FORM PRODUCED BY EQUIFAX') === FALSE) {
            $output .= substr($report, $position, 80) . '<br>';
        }

        if ($i == 32) {
            $output .= '</pre><pre>';
        }
        $position += 81;
    }
    $output .= '</pre>';
    return $output;
}
```

Here is screenshot how pdf looks like.

[image]

Please help me to improve the timing of pdf, currently taking more than 10min for 10-page pdf.

Comment: You might want to debug and check the flow itself when the document is being generated. PDF generators tend to have a problem where an issue arrises it gets stuck in a loop and it actually escapes it at some point but the time might vary. Debug over the whole generating process and try to undestand what's going on data wise. We just fixed a similar issue and in our case it was due to disallowing some blocks to be split resulting in an infinite loop if the block was "too big". 10 pages of data might get the same effect. The infine loop will escape itself at some point.

Comment: @Martin I have debugged the code and found that the pdf is generated within few seconds if I removed the `<pre>` tag from the formatting, it seems that the writing the spaces and formatting on the pdf generate taking longer time.